# lighter background-image CSS3

Tags: css

I have want to have a background-image one frame, but i need to make the image lighter. I have tried using opacity, but then a background image from another frame shines throungh. I also have some text in the same frame, and i don't want that text to get lighter.

I write in CSS3, here is my code;

```
        .frameContent
     {
        background-image: url(/image/and_02.jpg); 
        background-size: 100%;
        vertical-align: top; 
        border-left: #FFFFFF 20px solid;
        border-right: #FFFFFF 20px solid;
        border-top: #FFFFFF 15px solid;
        padding: 25px 10px 10px 10px;
        height:100%;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px;
    }
```

Comment: can you post the html to make it clear which frame you need the lightened image?

Answer (score 13):

As Bappi Das said, there is no background-opacity property. But `background-image` can take multiple parameters. We can use this to add some white in front of the image. Unfortunately, we cannot simply specify a color, but we can specify a gradient. So if we specify a gradient with two times the same color and make that color slightly transparent using `rgba`, we can alter the color of an image.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)),
                  url("/image/and_02.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this to the container element:

```
yourImageContainer:after {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; 
  background: hsla(180,0%,50%,0.25);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

this will put a darker/lighter mask depending on what color you chose.

Answer (score 0):

How about create nested elements?

.frame = Plain white;
.frameContent = your partially transparent Background

```
<div class="frame"><div class="frameContent">My Content here</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following css to your class ()

```
.frameContent
     {
        background-image: url(/image/and_02.jpg); 
        background-size: 100%;
        vertical-align: top; 
        border-left: #FFFFFF 20px solid;
        border-right: #FFFFFF 20px solid;
        border-top: #FFFFFF 15px solid;
        padding: 25px 10px 10px 10px;
        height:100%;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px;
        opacity: 0.2; 
        filter: alpha(opacity=20);
    }
```

and check if it works for you. You can also check following links for your reference

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/
http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-background-image-hacks/demo/opacity.html

Answer (score 0):

**There is no CSS property background-opacity, but you can achieve it by inserting a pseudo element (::after) behind it.**

```
.frameContent{
    position:relative;
    border-left: #FFFFFF 20px solid;
    border-right: #FFFFFF 20px solid;
    border-top: #FFFFFF 15px solid;
    padding: 25px 10px 10px 10px;
    height:100%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px;
}

.frameContent::after{
   content: "";
   background: url(/image/and_02.jpg);
   background-size:cover;
   opacity: 0.5;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: -1;
}
```